# Update entity after a sproc and inside a transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

Incoming analogy.

```
class Herd
{
    public List<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}

class Animal
{
    //at least for today, animals have opinions
    public List<Opinion> Opinions { get; set; }
}

class Opinion { }
```

We want to do a one-time move of different herds from the eastern US to the western US. We create a transaction for every herd we move. In that transaction, we call a few stored procedures. One of them adds some default opinions to the animals. Later on in the C# code in the same transaction, we add opinions manually to the animals, but they are dependent on the default opinions.

```
using (var trans = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        _context.Herds.Add(herd);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        Proc1Wrapper(herd);
        Proc2Wrapper(herd);
        Proc3Wrapper(herd);
        InsertDefaultOpinionsProc(herd);

        //this does not load the default opinions:
        herd = _context.Herds.Where(o => o.HerdID == herd.ID).First();

        //this does not either:
        herd = _context.Herds.Find(herd.ID);

        //this doesn't either:
        _context.Entry(herd).Reload();

        //this **does** load the default opinions
        foreach (var animal in herd.Animals)
            _context.Entry(animal).Collection("Opinions").Load();

        //dependent on default opinions
        AddOpinionsManually(herd);

        _context.SaveChanges();
        trans.Commit();
    }
    catch 
    {
        trans.Rollback();
        throw;  
    }
}
```

With a bunch of stored procedures being called, I'd like to just treat the entire herd as dirty and reload the herd object, but I can't find a way to do this. What am I missing?

Comment: The analogy probably would have been better with something like `FavoritePlaces` or `FavoriteFoods` instead of `Opinions`, as it's more obvious that they're dependent on location. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

If you trace this code with [SQL Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms175047.aspx) you will see that default opinions will not be available for the new herd until `trans` is committed (I assume you are using the default SQL Server isolation level of [ReadCommitted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)). You can solve this by using nested transactions.

```
//this will start a new transaction
using (var trans = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    try
    {
        _context.Herds.Add(herd);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        //this will use the "ambient" transaction but can commit separately
        using (wrapperTransaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
        {
            Proc1Wrapper(herd);
            Proc2Wrapper(herd);
            Proc3Wrapper(herd);
            InsertDefaultOpinionsProc(herd); 
            wrapperTransaction.Commit() //now your default opinions are inserted into the db
        }

        //this should return the herd now fully opinionated :)
        herd = _context.Herds.First(o => o.HerdID == herd.ID);

        AddOpinionsManually(herd);

        _context.SaveChanges();
        trans.Commit();
    }
    catch 
    {
        trans.Rollback();
        throw;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll test this as soon as I get the project in a compilable state again (it might be 24 hours unfortunately).

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test it yet. I have a deadline to hit and a lot of code to write. I'll check it as soon as possible, and if it works, I'll upvote and accept.

Comment: Thanks man. Just to keep you updated, I'm almost done with getting it to compile again.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. It runs, but it doesn't load the opinions.